# Manipulating this dictionary to return desired output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm working with a dictionary that contains sub-dictionaries. I would like to convert this to a usable format so that I can return just the desired value/output.

EDIT- I should add for context that this is a texting app. The top level key correlates to a particular 'conversation', while the sub-keys are individual 'messages'. The function I'm trying to create should be able to return the text of the newest 'message' from any given 'conversation' dictionary provided as input.

Here's an example dictionary:

```
mydict = {1005672: {4461048: {'body': 'Mnow test test', 'msg_id': 4461048},
                    4620511: {'body': 'test sms,test sms', 'msg_id': 4620511},
                    4620584: {'body': 'test sms', 'msg_id': 4620584},
                    4646648: {'body': 'test sms', 'msg_id': 4646648},
                    4646877: {'body': 'test sms', 'msg_id': 4646877},
                    5327736: {'body': 'testing again\r\n', 'msg_id': 5327736},
                    5332767: {'body': 'testing testing 1..2...3...', 'msg_id': 5332767},
                    5333204: {'body': 'testing the convID part...', 'msg_id': 5333204},
                    5333257: {'body': 'take 2!', 'msg_id': 5333257},
                    5333489: {'body': 'aaaaaaaaaaaand ACTION!', 'msg_id': 5333489},
                    5337141: {'body': 'does it work?', 'msg_id': 5337141},
                    5363443: {'body': 'Test', 'msg_id': 5363443},
                    5365638: {'body': 'testing again', 'msg_id': 5365638},
                    5366005: {'body': 'testing sms ID', 'msg_id': 5366005}}}
```

This allows me to explicitly return specific keys like this (which is a good start):

```
print(mydict[1005672][5366005])
```

However, I need to write a function that can return just the 'body' text for the *last* (or newest) item.
For example, I would like the function to return `'testing sms ID'`, for this example.

I would assume the way to go about this would be to first convert to a list, then slice?

```
mylist = list(mydict.values())
myslice = mylist[-1:]
```

However when I do that, it doesn't work, and continues to return the entire thing (albeit, now in  a list format!)

So I would like some guidance on how to do this- first slice the list to grab just the last line, but then how would I go about grabbing just the text between ' ' after body?

I appreciate any input on this. I am still learning so I appreciate any helpful tips. 
Thanks

Comment: Does the highest msg_id correspond to the "last (or newest)" item?

Comment: @ajp619, that is correct

Comment: What is the outer id (`1005672`)? Can there be multiple keys at that level? And how would that affect your desired output?

Comment: @tzaman , yes- this is a texting app. The outer ID correlates to a 'conversation' (messages between 2 particular parties). The sub-keys are messages. There can be multiple keys at the top level (conversations). I need to write a function to return the newest message body text, regardless of which conversation dictionary is fed as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
mydict = {1005672: {4461048: {'body': 'Mnow test test', 'msg_id': 4461048},
           4620511: {'body': 'test sms,test sms', 'msg_id': 4620511},
           4620584: {'body': 'test sms', 'msg_id': 4620584},
           4646648: {'body': 'test sms', 'msg_id': 4646648},
           4646877: {'body': 'test sms', 'msg_id': 4646877},
           5327736: {'body': 'testing again\r\n', 'msg_id': 5327736},
           5332767: {'body': 'testing testing 1..2...3...', 'msg_id': 5332767},
           5333204: {'body': 'testing the convID part...', 'msg_id': 5333204},
           5333257: {'body': 'take 2!', 'msg_id': 5333257},
           5333489: {'body': 'aaaaaaaaaaaand ACTION!', 'msg_id': 5333489},
           5337141: {'body': 'does it work?', 'msg_id': 5337141},
           5363443: {'body': 'Test', 'msg_id': 5363443},
           5365638: {'body': 'testing again', 'msg_id': 5365638},
           5366005: {'body': 'testing sms ID', 'msg_id': 5366005}}}

def get_latest(my_dict):
    latest_key = max(my_dict.keys())
    return my_dict[latest_key]["body"]


my_new_dict = {k: get_latest(mydict[k]) for k in mydict.keys()}

conversation_id = 1005672

my_new_dict[conversation_id]
>>> 'testing sms ID'

get_latest(mydict[conversation_id])
>>> 'testing sms ID'
```

Comment: A dictionary doesn't have a concept of "latest" since it is unordered, which is why I'm sorting the keys.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I realize dicts don't have a 'latest' which is why i was thinking of converting to a list. But anyways, the problem with your example is that I would need to explicitly know and declare the '1005672' number... that can and will change based on which dictionary is fed into the function. Function needs to be able to grab the last entry no matter which dictionary is fed in.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this, but I'm not quite following what you're after. Will mydict have multiple top level keys? Are you looking for something that  takes that top level key and returns the latest subkey? f(top_level_key) -> 'testing sys ID'?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not quite able to explain this well. This is a texting app. The top level key correlates to a 'conversation'. The sub-keys are messages. I'm trying to grab the newest message for any given 'conversation'.

Comment: @ajp619: In Python 3.6+, `dict`s are insertion-ordered, and as of 3.8, they support `reversed`, so you can get the newest (not necessarily numerically highest) key with `next(reversed(somedict))`. Beyond that, using `sorted` here is wasteful; it's `O(n log n)` work (with `O(n)` temporary storage) for something that should be `O(n)` work/`O(1)` storage. `max(d)` will do what `sorted(d.keys())[-1]` does, faster (the `.keys()` isn't necessary either, since `dict`s are already iterables of their keys; you only need `.keys()` when you want support for set operations like `&`, `|`, `^`).

Comment: @boog If you are given conversation_id = 1005672, then can't you also use `get_latest(mydict[conversation_id])` without creating my_new_dict?

Comment: @ajp619 just tested it out, it does work to accomplish half of what I'm trying to do. it returns both the newest value and key like this:
{1005672: 'testing sms ID'}... 
would I then convert this to a list and slice out that I want?

Comment: @boog I edited my dictionary comprehension to include the `k:` in the beginning. Try that. :-)

Comment: @ajp619, yes it's very close to what I'm looking for and a great answer, however I'm still getting the entire last/newest dictionary.... how would I pull just the value from it without explicitly stating print(dict[1005672])?

Comment: @ajp619 - I know this works but I still continue to get the full key printed out, can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here... but thank you for the answer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207311/discussion-between-ajp619-and-boog).

Answer (score 1):

The dictionnary is strange. It's nested. There's only one key/value pair at the highest level.

Extract it, then sort the dictionary contained as value and work your way with subscripting/key access:

```
>>> sorted(list(mydict.values())[0].items())[-1][1]["body"]
'testing sms ID'
```

note that unless the order of the dictionary is guaranteed (python 3.6), sorting the keys (assuming that highest key is the latest inserted) is the best method.

Comment: Note: We're getting close to [Python 3.5's end of life](https://devguide.python.org/#status-of-python-branches) in September, 2020 (2.x and 3.4 and earlier are already end of life). Pretty soon we can stop qualifying assertions about the insertion-ordered behavior of `dict`! :-)

Comment: you're right. But end of life doesn't mean it's not going to be used by companies who have specific pyd extensions or non-portable code.

Answer (score 1):

Not a function, but here is one way to do this:

```
dlookup = {k: max(v.keys()) for k, v in mydict.items()}

myid = 1005672
mydict[myid][dlookup[myid]]['body']
```

This will output `testing sms ID`

Answer (score 1):

I think the code below should work.

```
def r(dictionary):
    val = dictionary.values()
    for element in val:
        if not isinstance(element, dict):
            last_element = val
        else:
            last_element = element

    if isinstance(last_element, dict):
        r(last_element)
    else:
        for i in last_element:
          a = i
          break
        print(a)
```

so you can just call the function and pass in the dictionary as argument

Comment: that would be nice, unfortunately it returns everything, followed by '5366005', so i think it's close!.. I think the problem lies somewhere in the fact that there's the top level dictionary with all of the sub-dictionaries contained within?

Comment: I think there's a mistake. I ran the code with your dictionary and it prints "testing sms id" like you have requested.

Comment: Well I think part of the reason there are discrepencies in the output is because I created that dictionary in the original post as an example. The real data set that I'm working with is a JSON response from an api/endpoint obtained via the requests library. I believe that your answer works for my example, so you're not wrong, but in my case I think when working with a json response, therein somewhere lies the problem.

Comment: I thought as much. I think you should be able to modify the program to suit your needs if you wish.

Comment: I will work with it and see what I can do- thank you!